# I've encountered this error message - Error in fetch(key) : cannot allocate memory block of size 3.2 Gb

Tags: r, memory, logistic-regression, glm

I've used memory.limit() to enhance it to the 4GB limit that R has told me I have, but, I need to run ggPlot2 on the data I have which I'm unable to do so without more memory. Is this simply an issue with the RAM on my computer or is there a way around this?

Comment: When does the error occur? When reading the data? Transforming the data? Or plotting the data? Where does logistic regression come into play?

Comment: At the point of entering ggPlot2 into my script. I have imported the data, run anova() and then predict() and when I begin to write ggPlot2() into the script the error appears in the console